# Image not loading with the script

Tags: html

The image is not loading when I am using this script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"/>
</head>
<body>
    <img href="https://static.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg" width="200" height="267" alt="me">
</body>
</html>
```

If I remove the script I'm getting the `Image.Code:`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg" width="200" height="267" alt="me">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <script> </script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<script>` element [can't be self-closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work) (`<.../>`). You have to close the element with `</script>`. There is also a mistake on your `<img>` element. You are using the attribute `href`. In case the `<script>` would work your image is still not visible. You have to use the attribute `src` to show the image.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <title>test</title>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg" width="200" height="267" alt="me">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You din't close **script tag**

use

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Please check !!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>test</title>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg" width="200" height="267" alt="me">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using **script** tag at the end of body. Also, **script** tag is not a **void element** in html, you are not closing your **script** tag. Try using the following code:

```
<head>
        <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img href="https://static.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg" width="200" height="267" alt="me" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/alibs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
```